# get the next two words in a string

Tags: java

I'm building an autocomplete suggester and I'm trying to parse my suggestion.

I have the following code which allows me search for the keyword `wor` and return the whole word `keyword` and the remainder of the phrase. I'd like to add to this so that I only return up to a maximum of two additional words after the original word `keyword`.

```
Example code 

String keyword = "wor";
String phrase = "my keyword search phrase works";
int keywordIndex = phrase.indexOf(keyword);
int lastSpaceIndex = phrase.substring(0, keywordIndex).lastIndexOf(' ');
phrase = phrase.substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1);
```

That works perfectly to return `keyword search phrase works` from `wor`

but now I need to add to it so that I add up to a maxinum of 2 additional words when they exist from the phrase. Example `keyword search phrase`

I thought I could do something like this, but it doesn't work

```
if(phrase.contains(" ")) {                       
    int nextWordIndex = phrase.indexOf(" ");
    String result = phrase.substring(keywordsIndex, nextWordIndex);

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Could someone help me to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: You could split the string a collection of words. Would be easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensure you have two or more spaces then this would help:

```
phrase = phrase.substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1);
int firstIndex = phrase.indexOf(' ', 0);
int secondIndex = phrase.indexOf(' ', firstIndex + 1);
int thirdIndex = phrase.indexOf(' ', secondIndex + 1);
phrase = phrase.substring(0, phrase.indexOf(' ', thirdIndex));
System.out.println(phrase);
```

If you ensure you have spaces between the word then you could do the following:

```
String str[] = phrase.split(" ");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i =0; i< Math.min(str.length, 3); i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(str[i] + " ");
}

System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString().replaceAll(" $", ""));
```